# How can i run reactjs locally on mac other than the npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just a bit annoyed by having to do `npx create-react-app` and wait then **delete** most of the files and code.

I've seen some people use `npm i react react-dom`, is this another way as well?

can i also use react **offline** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  in your html if you don't want to use create-react-app. Then just create a file with that name. Otherwise I believe other methods still give you a boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Even if without `create-react-app`, can make React applications. But it's bother than with it. `create-react-app` just automates downloading libraries and many many configurations. So what they do is same.

Answer (score 0):

Create react app creates spa and gives entire folder structure out of the box, but you don't always need to use cra command for that, you can create spa yourself with minimal packages if you know the actual working of spa, you can use react, webpack, webpack dev server, babel.